# Split a CSV file into smaller files based on some condition

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a file with below values:

```
Server1,12.22.21.13,1234,Kevin@xyz.com
Server2,12.12.12.12,1223,Kevin@xyz.com
Server3,13.11.11.11,1234,John@xyz.com
Server4,11.11.11.11,1234,Chris@xyz.com
```

I want to split the file on the basis of email address. All the lines having email as **Kevin@xyz.com** should come in a file named **file1** and so on.

It is a very large file and I cannot hard code all the email IDs in a case statement.

Comment: is the input file sorted by email address? for ex, `Kevin@xyz.com` are all next to each other?

Comment: Yes the file is sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(gawk)

```
awk -F"," '{ print $0 >> $4".csv"}' filename
```

Expl:

```
-F"," -- Use "comma" field separator (FS) 
$0 -- the whole line of input
$4 -- the 4-th field of line ($NF -- the last field)
>> -- redirection operator, from `info gawk':

'print ITEMS >> OUTPUT-FILE'
  This redirection prints the items into the preexisting output file
  named OUTPUT-FILE.  The difference between this and the single-'>'
  redirection is that the old contents (if any) of OUTPUT-FILE are
  not erased.  Instead, the 'awk' output is appended to the file.  If
  OUTPUT-FILE does not exist, then it is created.
```

Comment: Please explain what your awk script does.

Comment: @taifwa: in a nutshell : with "," as separator:  he writes the whole line into a file named $4.csv, so as $4 is the email adress it writes each lines into the file named "email.csv" (in awj :    `$4 ".csv"` concatenes both together, and thus print $0 is appending (>>) to a file named: $4.csv,   $4 being replaced by the email@ listed on that current line). Hence all the same email adresses (ex: Kevin@xyz.com) informations end up in the same file (named Kevin@xyz.com.csv). Good and simple approach (and the file doesn't even need to have the input sorted by email adresses)

Comment: @Olivier I meant in-answer. Answers should ideally be properly fleshed out, not one-liners... the current state still does not explain how the awk script was construcuted, following what logic.